# Error While Installing Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed .net framework 2.0 and now I am trying to install Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition from the Internet, but when I execute the setup file I am getting the following error:

"The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch".

Can anyone tell me what is the error and how should I rectify it?

Please note that I am already having Visual Studio 2008 installed on my system.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you'll find the accepted way to get multiple versions of VS installed on the same pc is to install them in the order they were released in. Other ways may introduce problems.

Comment: Which bit are you installing? C#? Web Developer? Even the full Express DVD makes you do them one by one. Is this error when trying to install the prerequisites?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to install the Service Pack or an invalid file. When installing Visual Studio 2008 and choosing the default installation mode it will already install SQL Server 2005 Express edition on your machine if it is not already installed.

If you did a custom install you can re-run the Visual Studio 2008 installation and select to install SQL Express.

Also make sure you don't have Sql Server 2008 installed, and if you have do an advanced install on Sql Server 2005 express and change the instance name to something else. I would recommend rather installing Sql Server 2008, either from the internet or from the Sql Server Installation Disc, by choosing Express edition during installation.